# Converting lme4 ranef output to data frame with RPy2

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe, rpy2, lme4

I'm trying out Rpy2 and feeling pretty stumped. I passed in my pandas data frame and ran a mixed effects model with

```
m_rt = lme4.lmer(formula,verbose=True)
out = r.ranef(m_rt)
```

If I print out, it looks as expected:

```
$cat
               (Intercept) gen       delta
x        0.093546331   -0.168458284  0.144213098
y       -0.082592717    0.148733010 -0.127326764
z        0.005229467   -0.009417228  0.008061863
```

Now I want to pass that information back into a pandas data frame. Or really, any python object I can work with! I tried `pandas2ri.ri2py(out)` and got

```
<ListVector - Python:0x118b53248 / R:0x7fe3663a3238>
[DataFrame]
<ListVector - Python:0x118b53248 / R:0x7fe3663a3238>
[DataFrame]
```

and `r.data.frame(out)` and got `AttributeError: 'SignatureTranslatedFunction' object has no attribute 'frame'`
. I can't install dplyr because of some conflict with pandas data frame definitions -- maybe that's why. Is that normal? That error below:

```
LibraryError: Conflict when converting R symbols in the package "dplyr" to    Python symbols: 
-obj_type_data_frame -> obj_type.data_frame, obj_type.data.frame
To turn this exception into a simple warning use the parameter `on_conflict="warn"\`
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: the data frame is wrapped in a list.

Comment: What version of rpy2 do you have ? `import rpy2; print(rpy2.__version__)`

Comment: I have version 2.7.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there's a much easier way to do it than I was doing it. I had been using the template from [here](http://memory.osu.edu/classes/python/lessons/lsn11.html)

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
r_df = pandas2ri.py2ri(p_df)

# add all the fields to an environment
env = Environment()
for varname in r.colnames(r_df):
    env[varname] = r_df(varname)

formula = Formula('x ~ gen + delta + ( 1 + gen + delta | cat )',
              environment=env)
m_rt = lme4.lmer(formula,verbose=True)
```

And from there could `print r.summary(m_rt)` and `print r.fixef(m_rt)`, but couldn't get more to work.

But an easier way (I'm in a jupyter notebook), is:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%Rpush p_df
```

(Next cell)

```
%%R
library(lme4)
m_rt <- lmer(x ~ gen + delta + ( 1 + gen + delta | cat ) ),
        data = p_df)

rfs <- ranef(m_rt)$cat
ffs <- fixef(m_rt)
```

(Next cell)

```
%Rpull rfs
%Rpull ifs
```

And voila, rfs is now a pandas data frame, and ffs is an array.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is trying help you here:

> To turn this exception into a simple warning use the parameter `on_conflict="warn"\`

Doing as advised will let you import `dplyr`:

```
dplyr = importr("dplyr", on_conflict="warn")
```

This is what is done [in rpy2's own wrapper for dplyr](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/d1df48cf70cb5a5eb793bb2c7eef653533e89d33/rpy/robjects/lib/dplyr.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#dplyr.py-7).
While at it you may want to use that wrapper if interested in `dplyr` (this is [covered in the doc](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/lib_dplyr.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same issue, I believe what you saw "out" as an R object as below:

R object with classes: ('ranef.mer',) mapped to: [ListSexpVector]
Group:

My solution is accessing it as python data frame like this:

out[0]
re_campaign[0]